# How do I increment a variable as another is being incremented?

Tags: java, loops, increment

I am trying to create a program in Java in which a monthly service charge is to increase by $1 for every withdrawal after the 4th withdrawal (bank account program). I've tried to use a loop, but it just got stuck.

Code:

```
    public void monthlyProcess() {
    int w = getWithdrawals();
    if (w > 4) {
        while(w > 4) {
            serCharge++;
        }
    }
    super.monthlyProcess();
    if(bal <= MIN_BAL) {
        status = false;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think you got yourself an infinite loop there.

Comment: your "business logic" seems illogical.

Comment: `while(w > 4) {serCharge++;}` you need to change `w` inside loop or use some break/return to escape from it.

Comment: We need the whole context. Cannot figure out what should be the business rule. What does `super.monthlyProcess()` do?

Comment: Yeah, I know. When I tried 
while (wtm++) {serCharge++}
it said I was trying to convert from int to bool

Comment: `while (wtm++) {serCharge++}` Java doesnt support changing `0->false`, `1(or else)->true` so you cant use `while (wtm++)` but you could try with something like `while (wtm++ != 0)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, this should work.

Cheers!

```
public void monthlyProcess() {
    int w = getWithdrawals();
    if (w > 4) {
        serCharge += w - 4;
    }
    super.monthlyProcess();
    if(bal <= MIN_BAL) {
        status = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just `surcharge += w-4` ?

edit:

`surcharge += Math.max(w-4,0)`

Answer (score 3):

Looks like an infinitive loop to me, but overall I don't think you need a loop altogether:

```
 public void monthlyProcess() {
    int w = getWithdrawals();
    if (w > 4) {
           while(w > 4) {
            serCharge++;
            w--;
         }

    }
    super.monthlyProcess();
    if(bal <= MIN_BAL) {
        status = false;
    }
}
```

should do it

You got the infinitive loop, as since you was doing nothing to the w variable it would always be greater then four, so the loop would never break. and if it did you would end up with a massive service charge anyway, as it will keep incrementing because of the infinitive loop

"A programmer is out getting some milk, his wife calls him and says, ' while out can you pick up some eggs'... he never returns"

Comment: -1 : the OP wants to increment by 1$ the service charge for **every** withdrawal after the 4th. Your solution just increments by 1$ if more than 4 withdrawals.

Comment: Wouldn't this just increment serCharge if the value of wtm is over 4 just one time? I need serCharge to increment as wtm increments (after wtm == 4)

Comment: Sorry i read the question wrong, I thought this was being called every transaction. Updated Answe

Comment: @AlexisPigeon How it will be updated while the loop is true, until w because == 4?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers so far correctly point you towards getting rid of the `while` loop altogether, but for completeness sake, here's a solution that will keep that loop:

```
public void monthlyProcess() {
    int w = getWithdrawals();
    if (w > 4) {
        while(w > 4) {
            serCharge++;
            // make sure you update the value of w, 
            // otherwise you'll be stuck in an infinite loop!
            w--; 
        }
    }
    super.monthlyProcess();
    if(bal <= MIN_BAL) {
        status = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Way to back out of the infinite loop!